# Comparing String and Integer with equals

Tags: java, string, integer

The output of the below code is `false`

```
String str = "3456";
String str1 = "3456";
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(str).equals(str1));
```

I didn't understand it. I thought it will return `true`. As I am preparing for SCJP, understanding the reason behind it may be helpful.

Comment: Why should the be equal? One is a `Integer` object, the other a `String` object. That's a big difference... One represents a numeric value, the other a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `Integer` will never be `equal` to a `String`.

Both classes have very strict `equals()` definitions that *only* accept objects of their respective types.

- [`Integer.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

  > The result is true if and only if the argument is not `null` and **is an `Integer` object** that contains the same int value as this object.
- [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

  > The result is true if and only if the argument is not `null` and **is a `String` object** that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

That's actually a quite common way to implement `equals()`: only objects of the same class (and occasionally subclasses) *can* be equal. Other implementations are possible, but are the exception.

One common exception are the collections [such as `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29): every `List` implementation that follows the convention will return `true` when compared to *any other* implementation, if it has the same content in the same order.

Comment: oh ok..i got it now..but shouldn't equals written in such a way so as to give compile time error in this case?

Comment: @Anand: no, that's why `equals()` is a method of `Object`: you are allowed to *ask* if two objects are equal, no matter what types.

Comment: but if types are different, it's not going to work i.e. will always return false

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when implementing `equals()`, one of the first things to do is to check whether the objects are of one and the same type.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof SomeType)) return false;
    ...
}
```

This is also applied in the `Integer` and `String` classes, which answers the question why do you receive `false` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The general contract of the equals() methods states (among other things) that the objects that are being compared need to be of the same class. That's why you'll never be able to compare Apples with Oranges.

For the full contract of the equals() method, see the javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

a Integer Object can't equals with String Object

use :

```
boolean a = str.equals(str1);
```

OR

```
boolean a = (Integer.parseInt(str) == Integer.parseInt(str1));
```

Comment: Which is better practice?