# Why won't "5".equals(5) evaluate to true? Aren't they both they same, both being 5?

Tags: java, equals

I am new to Java and was wondering why "5".equals(5) evaluate to true meaning both are a 5 and in my eyes seem to be the same thing (they seem equal to me) so why won't it evaluate it to true?

I am thankful for any help :)

Comment: java is statically typed. google it.

Comment: They are not the same. Why would you assume that? If they are "the same", what does ``5.equals("5")`` do?

Comment: JavaScript has an operator (`==`) that behaves this way. Most people nowadays recommend not to use it in favor of `===` because of some strange effects.

Comment: One example for the "Strange Effects" that you encounter when using of such lenient equality checks is that it gets hard to keep it transient: you say String "5" is basically the same as Character '5' or Integer 5, but then someone suggest that it should also work with roman literals - "V" is also 5, after all. and suddenly you need to say that String "5" is equal to String "V" or abandon transitivity - you've got "A equals B" and "B equals C", but "A not equal to C" - which leads to all kinds of bugs and confusion.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546466/comparing-string-and-integer-with-equals for example.

Comment: @Hulk maybe an even better example for lost transitivity is `5.0` and `5.00` that are equal as numbers but not as strings.

Answer (score 7):

"5" is a String, while 5 is an integer, and the .equals method also compares the type

Answer (score 3):

A deeper look at the function what it actually does:

It checks if the value you have sent is an instance of `String`.

```
public boolean equals(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof String){
       // continue comparing..
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
```

if the value isn't an instance of `String` the method will return false,
in your case 5 is an instance of `Integer`.

That's why the method will return a false.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "5".equals(5);
```

could be written as:

```
 "5".equals(new Integer(5));
```

Just to make it clear: you are comparing a String object against an Integer object in the end (if there is really a `new Integer()` call, or `Integer.valueOf()` call doesn't matter here). There is no method `equals(int)` on the String class, so the compiler turns the `int` literal 5 into an Integer object for you (that is called **boxing**).

Thing is: in Java `equals()` methods (most often) take the type of Objects into account. A String can't be equal to an Integer, never ever. Independent of the "content" that the different objects "represent".